# QtCreator: Deploy Unit Test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, deployment, qt-creator, googletest

Is it possible to deploy googletest executables to a remote device by using the "Test" view (e.g. by clicking on "Run All Tests"?

The deployment should be configured correctly in my case, because after clicking "Run" or "Start Debugging" the executable is deployed and started on my device. The gtest output is then shown in the "Application Output".

But I want to run only test cases which are selected in the "Test" view and see the results in the "Test Results" view. 
When I click on "Run This Test" I get the error:

```
FATAL   Failed to start test for project "CommonTestbench".
Command line: /home/......./CommonTestbench --gtest_filter=_8_Utils.*
PATH: 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
Run configuration:  "CommonTestbench"
```

I think it skips the deploy step and tries to start the executable locally (which can not work, because it is compiled for an embedded system).

Is it possible to use the "Tests" and "Test Results" views in combination with remote devices?

Edit: I'm also not able to debug test cases. The debugger won't stop at any breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible yet, the current implementation can only deploy locally.

I've made a [feature request](http://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-21759) to add support for remote debugging support.